# form submits although onClick should return false

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I already checked [How to prevent form from being submitted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3350247/how-to-prevent-form-from-being-submitted?lq=1) but it did not help.

I have a register form with some input and a submit button

```
<script src="formValidation.js"></script> 
<script src="md5.js"></script>
<script language="javascript">
function doSomething() {   
str = document.registration.userpass.value;
str2 = document.registration.userpass2.value;
document.registration.response.value = MD5(str);
document.registration.response2.value = MD5(str2);
document.registration.userpass.value="";
document.registration.userpass2.value="";
formValidation();}


<form name="registration" action="/Arnito_test/Register" method="post"  >
<input onClick="return doSomething();" type=submit>
```

formValidation.js:

```
function formValidation() {
    ...
        if (registration.userpass.value == registration.username.value) {
            alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
           document.registration.userpass.focus();
            return false;
        }
...}
```

If I force this alert, it appears, but the form submits anyway.
the return false should block it, no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doSomething()` needs a `return` statement. The last line should be:

```
return formValidation();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try -

1. Add "event" as a parameter that doSomething gets
2. Send it to formValidation
3. Add   event.preventDefault();

   ```
   function doSomething(event) 
   {   
      str = document.registration.userpass.value;
      str2 = document.registration.userpass2.value;
      document.registration.response.value = MD5(str);
      document.registration.response2.value = MD5(str2);
      document.registration.userpass.value="";
      document.registration.userpass2.value="";
      formValidation(event);

   }

   function formValidation(event) {
                   if (registration.userpass.value == registration.username.value) {
               alert("Error: Password must be different from Username!");
               document.registration.userpass.focus();
               event.preventDefault();
               return false;
           }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use

```
<input onSubmit="return doSomething();" type=submit>
```